# Who do I credit to if someone modifies another person's answer?

Tags: discussion

The topic in question is
[Merging 2 lists while retaining the original data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152046/merging-2-lists-while-retaining-the-original-data/38152402)

An answer was posted but was incorrect.  This person then edited their post to include a modified version of a solution that someone else had posted as a comment on the question, which actually is correct.  BUT the twist is that the comment's solution did not work either but the modified version did.

So the reality is that the comment's solution at its essence was correct, but with some syntax problems. Another user fixed the syntax and posted it as an actual working answer.

I have no idea who should get the credit for this. I want to think the comment solution should, even if it had some syntax issues.

Comment: Upvote or accept correct *answers*.  Not people, it doesn't matter who wrote or edited it.

Comment: By "credit", do you mean reputation points or the BY in CC BY-SA?

Comment: To answer the title of the question: You always credit all authors or none, anything else wouldn't make sense, would it? So go through the version history and write down all names. But I guess you could choose to credit a previous version of the answer that does with less authors if already the previous version is good for you. They are all there but getting that right may also be some work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The edit in this case wasn't done by the commenter, it was done by the answerer. And while part may be based off another person's comment (with attribution), they still spent the time to put it all together.

That being said, if a commenter wants credit for answering, they need to post an answer. You can upvote their comment, but that counts for very little. It's not your job to prompt them to answer the question, but you can.

Until they post an answer, there will be just the one answer. Keep in mind that accepting the answer just means that it was helpful for you. You are free to change it at any time. Remember that you also have the ability to up vote answers that you feel were helpful, even if you don't accept them.

Comment: Side note: I would not say that accept is *alternative* to upvote. They are different even if both give rep points - so it makes sense to upvote and accept good useful answer (or even downvote and accept if answer is bad but helped you).

Comment: There are meta topics on answers in comments and I think this boils it down nicely "if a commenter wants credit for answering, they need to post an answer. "

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You're right that my wording was poor. I've changed it to be closer to my original intention: up voting and accepting are two independent, separate actions.